# opening logfile with boost and append some entries

Tags: c++, file, logging, boost

I've to write a little logger for custom entries. I use a boost class "boost::filesystem::fstream" for read and write. At first I open a logfile 
        _file.open( boost::filesystem::path( _fileName ), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary ); 
and read all entries from there. Then I write a new entrie, I get a "badbit"-exception.
What I make wrong?

Comment: you open it as "write only" (`std::ios_base::out` flag)

Comment: Oh, sorry. It was a wrong code. This is right line: _file.open( boost::filesystem::path( _fileName ), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary );